# Bootstrap SASS in Visual Studio 2013 wrong font path

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, sass

So,

I have used bower to install bootstrap SASS files into my application.
I am using AngularJS and want to use my own directory structure instead of the default **Content** path defined by MVC.
So I have installed https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass and in my core SASS file I have imported the bootstrap SASS like this:

```
@import "../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

everything loads in my application and the site is definitely using bootstrap, but whenever I try to use a glyphicon I just get a square instead of the icon. Looking in the console I can see that the path to the glyphicons is wrong. It is showing:

> http://localhost:58859/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

but it should be

> http://localhost:58859/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf

Now I "could" edit the variables file and change this line:

```
// [converter] If $bootstrap-sass-asset-helper if used, provide path relative to the assets load path.
// [converter] This is because some asset helpers, such as Sprockets, do not work with file-relative paths.
$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "../fonts/bootstrap/") !default;
```

to something like this:

```
// [converter] If $bootstrap-sass-asset-helper if used, provide path relative to the assets load path.
// [converter] This is because some asset helpers, such as Sprockets, do not work with file-relative paths.
$icon-font-path: "/assets/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts";
```

but whenever someone loads my project from github and bower resolves bootstrap my changes to that file will be lost. I have noted in their documentation they talk about sprockets and mincer, but I have never used these so I have no idea what they are for.

My question is, can I change the font path without editing the SASS file directly?

Comment: Just add the icon-font-path override to your core sass file, after the @import.

Comment: Would you mind sharing how your main sass file looks like? Just the include and the override.